# How do I use nprogress with aurelia webpack

Tags: aurelia

I've created a new aurelia project with webpack and I want to use my custom nprogress component

```
import { bindable, noView } from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as nprogress from 'nprogress';

@noView(['nprogress/nprogress.css'])
export class LoadingIndicator {
    @bindable public loading = false;

    private loadingChanged(newValue): void {
        if (newValue) {
            nprogress.start();
        } else {
            nprogress.done();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error at runtime: `Failed loading required CSS file: nprogress/nprogress.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webpack is not using `aurelia.json`.

just change it as follow:

```
import * as nprogress from 'nprogress';
import { bindable, noView } from 'aurelia-framework';

import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';

@noView()
export class LoadingIndicator {
  @bindable loading = false;

  loadingChanged(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      nprogress.start();
    } else {
      nprogress.done();
    }
  }
}
```

or change your css loader in `webpack.config.js`. More info here https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file called `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` if you generated your project via Aurelia CLI. In that file, there is a block `build.bundles.dependencies`. You need to add the following to the block:

```
"dependencies": [
  ...,
  {
    "name": "nprogress",
    "path": "../node_modules/nprogress",
    "main": "nprogress",
    "resources": [
      "nprogress.css"
    ]
  }
]
```